# Потеря контекста

Tags: javascript

```
HTMLElement.prototype.a = {
 a1: function(){ console.log(this) }
}
```

вернёт Object {},
А мне нужен HTMLElement.

Как быть ?

Comment: развернуть объект `.a`, если же нет возможности так поступить - явно задать нужный контекст через `.bind()`, `.call()` или `apply()`

Comment: Как эта функция вызывается? Вообще говоря - контекст тут не теряется, у вас есть объект, у него вызывается функция, вполне логично что этот объект показывается в виде `this`

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае контекст как раз не теряется.

у вас есть объект

```
{
 a1: function(){ console.log(this) }
}
```

у него вызывается функция, вполне логично что этот объект показывается в виде `this`.

Если нужен `HTMLElement` - пхайте функцию прямиком в прототип

```
HTMLElement.prototype.a = function(){ console.log(this); }
```

Но расширение стандартных прототипов не является хорошей идеей, особенно прототипов DOM элементов.

Comment: 1) HTMLElement.prototype.a = function(){ console.log(this); } - Спасибо кэп
2) "Но расширение стандартных прототипов не является хорошей идеей, особенно прототипов DOM элементов." - Почему ?

Comment: @Kirpich643, [например](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea)

Comment: а что тогда делать ? Как реализовать удобную работу с одним узлом ? `var $ = function (selector) {

    var node = function () {

    };

    node.prototype = document.querySelector( selector );

    return new node();

};` - $("body").innerHTML VM100:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)  Больше на ум ничего не приходит

Comment: @Kirpich643, чем не угодил подход jQuery? кроме того непонятно, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать в итоге

Comment: @Kirpich643, а также непонятно в чем смысл делать промежуточную функцию, если можно работать с результатом функции `document.querySelector`?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен инстанс `HTMLElement` (а все функции в прототипе, через `this`, как правило, будут ссылаться именно на инстанс класса), то есть еще специфический вариант вида:

```
var innerObject = {
 a1: function(){ console.log(this); }
};

Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "a", { 
    get: function () { 
        return Object.keys(innerObject).reduce(function(res, key){
            res[key] = innerObject[key].bind(this);
            return res;
        }.bind(this), {});
    } 
});
```

Но в целом, это не лучший вариант для использования. Прежде всего по названным @Grundy причинам.